# PDF signing with Adobe PDF reader

Tags: python, certificate, digital-signature, x509

I have a digital signature token and the customer wants to sign PDF documents like the process shared on the below link:

https://emudhradigital.com/kc/how-to-sign-pdf-with-a-digital-signature.jsp

Can someone guide me on what steps to follow? I can code well in Python so will appreciate a python library to do so. I can't afford to use any commercially available libraries. I checked but also couldn't find the appropriate library from Adobe to do this.

I have tried my hands around the PyHanko Library:

https://github.com/MatthiasValvekens/pyHanko

but I have not been able to get the same results.

The digital signature token contains the private key, public key and the certificate of an individual and I want to use that same in the process mentioned on the link. I am able to generate the signed hash from the token for the PDF and can read the certificate back in PEM format. I just don't know what I need to do to get integrated with Adobe Reader/Acrobat's process.